# aws cloudformation use Fn::Join in a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've a cloudformation template that uses custom resource backed by lambda function. One of the parameters of the lambda function is a list of strings. I have only one item to pass in the list and would like to use Fn:Join to concatenate create the string. However, using Fn::Join gives error as it leads to invalid json. Any inputs are appreciated.

"Subscriptions": [ "Fn::Join": [":", ["a", "b", "c"]]]

> A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the CreateStack
>   operation : Template format error: JSON not well-formed.

**Cloudformation snippet:-**

```
  "Resources": {
"MyCustomRes": {
      "Type": "Custom::CustomResource",
      "Properties": {
        "ServiceToken": { "Fn::Join": [ "", [
                                        "arn:aws:lambda:",
                                        { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
                                        ":",
                                        { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" },
                                        ":function:LambdaFn"
                                      ] ] },
        "Version": 1,
        "ResourceName": { "Ref": "ResourceName" },
        "Subscriptions"       : [ "Fn::Join": [ "", [
                                        "arn:aws:sns:",
                                        { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
                                        ":",
                                        { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" },
                                        ":Topic1"
                                      ] ] ]
    }
}     },
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`Fn::Join` Intrinsic Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) used to build the values for the `Subscriptions` property must be an object rather than an array.

It's invalid JSON syntax to declare an array like `['Fn::Join' : [...]]` instead it must be of the form  `{"Fn::Join" : [...]}`

The docs describe the syntax as

```js
{ "Fn::Join" : [ "delimiter", [ comma-delimited list of values ] ] }
```

Therefore your CloudFormation template should use the following

```json
{
  "Subscriptions": {
    "Fn::Join": [
      ":",
      [
        "arn:aws:sns",
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::Region"
        },
        {
          "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
        },
        "Topic1"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

A more readable solution to constructing ARN exists using the [`Fn::Sub` Intrinsic Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html#w2ab1c31c28c59b5).

```json
{
  "Fn::Sub": [
    "arn:${AWS::Partition}:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:Topic1"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What does "ref" do again?

Answer (score 10):

I arrived here looking for the same syntax in YAML files. What threw me there was needing to have two lists of args: a list with 2 items to Join, the second of which is a list itself. The full YAML syntax looks like this:

```
  SourceArn: 
    Fn::Join: 
    - ""
    - - 'arn:aws:execute-api:'
      - !Ref AWS::Region
      - ':'
      - !Ref AWS::AccountId
      - ':'
      - !Ref ApiGatewayRestApiResource
      - '/*'
```

Comment: I found this document under AWS 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html